# PHP using dropzone inside a form - files not moved the upload directory

Tags: php, forms, upload, dropzone

I have implemented dropzone inside an HTML form by following a tutorial. I have the the form set to process the files on a button click.  Once I click the button I see the files being processed but they are not being moved to the assigned upload directory. I'm wondering if I've missed a step somewhere in the script.  I've tried many suggestions found through stackoverflow and other resources but cannot find where I am going wrong ...still looking though.

I have some file validation using Dropzone, but want to get to the point where the files are moved before I finalize the validation and add the sql query to upload the files and the text to the database.

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form action="file_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <textarea class="form-control border-bottom" name="gallery_text" id="gallery_text" placeholder="Add gallery message..."></textarea>
  <div class="dropzone mt-3" id="myDropzone"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit" name="gallery_submit" id="gallery_submit"> Post Gallery </button>
</form>
```

...and here is the script:

```
<script>
Dropzone.options.myDropzone= {
    url: "file_upload.php",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    maxFiles: 5,
    maxFilesize: 2,
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictDuplicateFile: "Duplicate Files Cannot Be Uploaded",
    preventDuplicates: true,

    init: function() {
        dzClosure = this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.

        // for Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
        document.getElementById("gallery_submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            dzClosure.processQueue();
        });

        //send all the form data along with the files:
        this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append("gallery_text", jQuery("#gallery_text").val());
        });
    }
}
```

...and finally the upload PHP file:

```
    <?php require 'inc/config.php';

    $folder_name = 'assets/img/posts/';

    if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {
        $temp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $filename = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        $location = $folder_name . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $location);
    }
?>
```

For visual reference here are three screenshots of the process:

[image: Upload Form]

[image: After dropping the images]

[image: After clicking the Post Gallery button]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see anything wrong with your code, all I can say is that, you don't really need to call the `basename()` on `$_FILES['file']['name']`. The `basename()` is used to get the basename from a file path e.g 'C:/User/user/folder/file.txt'.

So try this below

```
 $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

Comment: Good call - changed that but the files are still not moving.  This is a head scratcher!

Comment: Make an else statement to go with the if statement, let's see if the $_FILE variable is empty, if it is then the code in the if statement block would not run obviously

Comment: I added an else echo statement - no output.  It's like it's not even getting to the file_upload.php

Comment: I think so too, so maybe you visit Dropzone's documentation and see if you're doing it right. I once tried using dropzone, it wasn't successful. I ended up using a jQuery plugin dmUploader

Comment: Yep - I'm back on their site digging - thanks for trying though - I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to update us with any info you have for future reference

Comment: Yep - need to leave a trail in case other folks have the same issue.

Comment: UPDATE:  I changed uploadMultiple to false and could upload one file so I "think" I need to loop through the files - still searching for the best way to do that.

Comment: So that means we're getting to the file_upload.php file?

Comment: Yes - since it moves a single file to the upload directory.  I'm going to try a loop in the file_upload.php and see if that works.

Comment: Bingo - I needed to loop through the files and upload each one.  I'll update using "answer your question".  You helped get me there - thanks for that!

Comment: Good call..... Here's a suggestion, change the uploadMultiple to true, then do a print_r on the $_FILE variable in the file_upload.php file, to see if it returns and array

Comment: Beautiful.....congrats, I can imagine how happy you are now. Am also happy you got it to work

Comment: Yeah - you know the feeling - spending hours trying, searching, testing, failing - then when you hit it it's like Christmas! :)

Comment:  Cheers to you for not giving up

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to loop through the files before they could be moved.  In file_upload.php I added a loop shown below.  This worked.

```
// Count # of uploaded files in array
$total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);


$filename_arr = [];
// Loop through each file
for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {

    //Get the temp file path
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

    //Make sure we have a file path
    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        //Setup our new file path
        $newFilePath = "assets/img/posts/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

        //Upload the file into the temp dir
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

            //Handle other code here
            //$filename_arr[] = $newFilePath;

        }
    }
}
```